# Sequence of ellipse menu items in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ellipses

I was wondering if it is possible to changes sequence of ellipse menu items.
In document library, currently when I click on 3 dots icon (as show in image), this shows me popup menu. Current sequence of this menu is "Open", "Share", "Follow", "Download" and so on.
I want to change this sequence and promote "Download" option to 2nd place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB way to change the order of menu items.

You need to use jQuery code to achieve it.

The demo for your reference:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    setInterval(changeECBOrder, 100);
});
function changeECBOrder(){
    var sTitle="Open";
    var tTitle="Download";
    if($(".js-callout-action>a[title^='"+sTitle+"']").length>0&&$(".js-callout-action>a[title^='"+tTitle+"']").length>0){
        $(".js-callout-action>a[title^='"+sTitle+"']").parent().after($(".js-callout-action>a[title^='"+tTitle+"']").parent());
    }              
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the order of elements on popup menu. It is an standar feature of SharePoint document libraries.